# Create automatically JAR with ANT and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jar

I want to make the file build automatically using Eclipse. I need this file creates the JAR of the application. And if it were possible, I would like to insert the command to pass some test of JUnit. How can I do all of this automatically?

Comment: Please add some more details. Will you run the build from _inside_ Eclipse? Or do you want to use `ant` from the command line, with a target that uses Eclipse to do a build?

Comment: Is using Maven instead of Ant an option?

Comment: I want to create this .build using Eclipse and then use ant without any change.

Eclipse-->create .build-->ant-->create .jar

Comment: No, I am using ant. I think that I have to insert some templates in Preferences->Ant->Editor->Templates but I am not sure

Answer (score 13):

Generally to create jar files in Eclipse I do this things:

1. create an ant file with the necessary code to create the jar file I need
2. configure the ant file to be processed when something change in my project files: and to do this I open the project *properties*, I choose *Builders*, *"New..."* and I add a *Ant builder* that use my ant file

In the ant files I put for example something similar:

```
<project name="My Project" default="createjar">    
  <property name="projectHome" location="." />
  <target name="createjar">
    <jar destfile="${projectHome}/file.jar" basedir="${projectHome}/bin" />
  </target>    
</project>
```

You can add other instructions to the ant file and process whatever you need after the jar creation. But my suggestion is to not launch JUnit test on very file change, can be very ugly.

Comment: I know this, but now I want to do automatically